# How to draw a line proportional to the height and width of screen size to each frame of a webcam outpun in openCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am a beginner to python and just started to learn the language recently in combination with openCV. My project group and I are trying to draw a grid to the webcam output in openCV. I did some research and found this function:

```
cv2.line(img, (img.shape[1] / 2, 0), (img.shape[1] / 2, img.shape[0]), 
(255, 0, 0), 1, 1)
```

which work for an image. In my case i want it to work on video output from my webcam, so i thought; why not just replace 'img' with 'frame', the idea works but i get an error:

> TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

I can understand the error as it expects an interger but gets a float instead. What is the work around for this problem?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Use `int(x/2) `